# wxPython: get data in variables from Google Spreadsheet and also from user, work with all variables, return results to user

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, wxpython, google-sheets

I hope I didn't miss any topic that could answer my problem. I'm here now because I'm terribly frustrated and tired with the following task: 
- I have a Spreasheet with Drive.Google with lots of data in it
- I would like to create an application with wxPython that would pull data from this spreeadsheet (in the most easy way possible)
- Would also like to get multiple data from a user who will access this application through a nice interface (panel aka window)
- The multiple data introduced by the user should be able to work with the data pulled out from the Spreasheet. For example to see if the data introduced by the user is in the Spreadsheet or not and also some other operations with the next data introduced by the user.
- Finally and most importantly show the results to the user (later I would also like to add some functions to save somehow the results)

I hope I managed to express clearly what I would like to do. Now I'm new to Google API's, Python adn wxPython, but I have experience with C++ , php, html . 
I've spent 2 weeks now with discovering Drive.Google and learning Python and wxPython. I did follow all tuturials on these, made my notes, read tones of stackoverflow questions-answers, wiki.wxpython.org etc. I learn every single day and I can do now many things separately but to have all functions like I described above I just couldn't work out how to do. At least please orient me in the direction. Awfel lot of times I spend hours doing examples and getting nowhere. I have Python, wxPython extention,  GoogleAppEngine Launcher and even pyCharm demo. Please be kind. This is my first question ever.

here's the mess I made so far combining relevant examples:

```
import wx
import gdata.docs
import gdata.docs.service
import gdata.spreadsheet.service
import re, os

class Form(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.createControls()
        self.bindEvents()
        self.doLayout()
        self.spreasht()

    def createControls(self):
        self.logger = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.saveButton = wx.Button(self, label="Elvegzes")
        self.nameLabel = wx.StaticText(self, label="type Name1:")
        self.nameTextCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="type here")
        self.name2Label = wx.StaticText(self, label="type Name2:")
        self.name2TextCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="type here") 


    def bindEvents(self):
        for control, event, handler in \
            [(self.saveButton, wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSave),
             (self.nameTextCtrl, wx.EVT_TEXT, self.onNameEntered),
             (self.nameTextCtrl, wx.EVT_CHAR, self.onNameChanged)]:
            control.Bind(event, handler)


    def doLayout(self):
             raise NotImplementedError


    def spreadsht(self):
        gd_client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
        gd_client.email = 'my email address'
        gd_client.password = 'my password to it'
        gd_client.source = 'payne.org-example-1'
        gd_client.ProgrammaticLogin()
        q = gdata.spreadsheet.service.DocumentQuery()
        q['title'] = 'stationcenter'
        q['title-exact'] = 'true'
        feed = gd_client.GetSpreadsheetsFeed(query=q)
        spreadsheet_id = feed.entry[0].id.text.rsplit('/',1)[1]
        feed = gd_client.GetWorksheetsFeed(spreadsheet_id)
        worksheet_id = feed.entry[0].id.text.rsplit('/',1)[1]

        al1 = raw_input('Name1: ')
        print al1
        al2 = raw_input('Name2: ')
        print al2

        rows = gd_client.GetListFeed(spreadsheet_id, worksheet_id).entry
        for row in rows:
            for key in row.custom:
                if al1 == row.custom[key].text:
                    print '  %s: %s' % (key, row.custom[key].text)


    def onColorchanged(self, event):
        self.__log('User wants color: %s'%self.colors[event.GetInt()])

    def onReferrerEntered(self, event):
        self.__log('User entered referrer: %s'%event.GetString())

    def onSave(self,event):
        self.__log('User clicked on button with id %d'%event.GetId())

    def onNameEntered(self, event):
        self.__log('User entered name: %s'%event.GetString())

    def onNameChanged(self, event):
        self.__log('User typed character: %d'%event.GetKeyCode())
        event.Skip()

    def onInsuranceChanged(self, event):
        self.__log('User wants insurance: %s'%bool(event.Checked()))

    # Helper method(s):

    def __log(self, message):
        ''' Private method to append a string to the logger text
            control. '''
        self.logger.AppendText('%s\n'%message)




class FormWithSizer(Form):
    def doLayout(self):
        ''' Layout the controls by means of sizers. '''
        boxSizer = wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.HORIZONTAL)
        gridSizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=5, cols=2, vgap=10, hgap=10)

        # Prepare some reusable arguments for calling sizer.Add():
        expandOption = dict(flag=wx.EXPAND)
        noOptions = dict()
        emptySpace = ((0, 0), noOptions)

        # Add the controls to the sizers:
        for control, options in \
                [(self.nameLabel, noOptions),
                 (self.nameTextCtrl, expandOption),
                 (self.allomas2Label, noOptions),
                 (self.allomas2TextCtrl, expandOption),
                  emptySpace,
                 (self.saveButton, dict(flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER))]:
            gridSizer.Add(control, **options)

        for control, options in \
                [(gridSizer, dict(border=5, flag=wx.ALL)),
                 (self.logger, dict(border=5, flag=wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND,
                    proportion=1))]:
            boxSizer.Add(control, **options)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(boxSizer)


class FrameWithForms(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FrameWithForms, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        notebook = wx.Notebook(self)
        form2 = FormWithSizer(notebook)
        notebook.AddPage(form2, 'CALTH')
        self.SetClientSize(notebook.GetBestSize())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(0)
    frame = FrameWithForms(None, title='Relevant title˝')
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

THANK YOU AGAIN!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you can download the data you want with just Python. Then create a wxPython GUI with a single button. In that button's handler, have it call the script that can download the data you want.

If that causes your GUI to become unresponsive, then you'll need to use a thread to do the downloading. I recommend the following articles if that's the case:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

Okay, so now you have the data downloading appropriately. Now you add a grid widget or a listctrl / object list view widget. Pick one of those. I prefer object list view, which you can read about [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/23/wxpython-using-objectlistview-instead-of-a-listctrl/). Then in your button handler you can call your downloader script or thread and when that's done, you can load the widget with that data. If you're using a thread, then the thread will have to call the next step (i.e. the widget loading bit).

Now you should have your data displayed. All that's left is making it look pretty and maybe putting the downloading part into a menu item.

Comment: Thank you very much. I deeply appreciate your answer and I'm already making relatively fast progress in my coding. I will publish here the code when it's done. Really, thanks Mike :)